# Obligatory authentication in Pyramid

Tags: python, pyramid

I am trying to build a website where authentication is obligatory, i.e. only login page is shown if user is not logged in. The question is how to achieve it with the minimal cost. I can decorate each view with

```
permission='authenticated'
```

where 'authenticated' is the name of my permission; but maybe there is a simpler way, where by default all views require authentication.

**Note**
I have accepted the answer below, but I believe there is more into it. Config bit:

```
config = Configurator(settings=settings,
                      default_permission='standard_view',
                      root_factory='RootFactory')
```

Security - permission bit:

```
class RootFactory(object):
    __acl__ = [(Allow, Authenticated, 'standard_view'),
               (Allow, 'g:admin', 'admin_view'),
    ]
```

Comment: Is your question not answered?

Comment: There is an answer - thanks a lot! - but I could not get it working yet. The whole authentication/authorization in Pyramid seems to be over-engineered :(

Comment: If you post your __init__.py and a view function, you could probably get more tailored guidance. Not sure what you mean by over-engineered, it allows you to set a global default in addition to fine-grained control per view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to do this by setting **`default_permission`** in the **`Configurator`** object. For example, in your **__init__.py** you can have something similar to:

```
from pyramid.config import Configurator

def main(global_config, **settings):
    config = Configurator(settings=settings, default_permission='authenticated')
    config.include('pyramid_chameleon')
    config.scan()
    return config.make_wsgi_app()
```

You can find more information at these three links:
http://docs.pylonsproject.org/docs/pyramid/en/latest/api/config.html
http://docs.pylonsproject.org/docs/pyramid/en/latest/narr/security.html#setting-a-default-permission
http://docs.pylonsproject.org/docs/pyramid/en/latest/api/config.html#pyramid.config.Configurator.set_default_permission

Comment: According to my final code - you need also to have RootFactory defined where the permission is defined.